# onkeyup js вывод не по порядку

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть поиск на сайте, который выдает инфу каждый раз, когда в нем появляется новый символ. То есть к примеру пишем `heroes`,- `h` - выдает результаты, которые удовлетворяют наличию этого символа.
Далее при наборе - `he`.  Далее - `her`, `hero`, `heroe`, `heroes`, ну в общем мысль в этом. Однако, если быстро напечатать слово `heroes`, то в консоли результат совершенно не тот, который должен быть:

`hero, heroes, he, her, heroe, h , he` - и результат разумеется выдает по последнему запросу - `he...`

В коде ничего особенного, обычный:

```
 $("#appname").on('keyup',function(){ }
```

Подскажите, есть ли способ с этим бороться?

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону промисов, может запускать функцию обработки только по завершению предыдущей обработки?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте событие `input` , чтобы посимвольно отлавливать изменения
На чистом JS

```js
var appname = document.getElementById('appname');
appname.oninput = function(){
  console.log(this.value);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="appname">
```

на JQuery

```js
$('#appname').on('input', function(){
  console.log(this.value)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="appname">
```

Comment: я так и знал, что есть какое-то простое решение)))

Comment: скорость увеличилась еще и раза в 2 =)

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял, то быстро наборное слова может вывестись в консоль не полностью, например у него не будет последней буквы. Способ с этим бороться есть, нужно использовать `setTimeout(...,0)` подробнее об этом написано [здесь](http://learn.javascript.ru/keyboard-events#%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0) (ищите предупреждающий треугольник).

Comment: не подойдет, тк если я поставлю таймаут, он может запросто не заметить, если я вобью еще 1 букву, то есть он обрабатывает первую по таймауту, а я там уже все 6 вбил, а он не видел остальных 5, тк таймаут

Comment: Вам нужно сделать так, чтобы `setTimeout(...,0)` срабатывал только в самом конце печати, причем еще нужно будет определить скорость набора текста, что бы он не сработал последний раз, когда кто-то будет набирать слишком медленно.